# Android: how set image view outside of the activity

Tags: android, imageview

ImageRenderer.java

```
public class ImageRenderer implements Renderer {
...

private Context mActivityContext;
...

public SandAniRenderer(final Context activityContext) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    mActivityContext = activityContext;
    mField = new Field(mActivityContext);
    ...
}

private boolean InitializeObject(int width, int height)
{
    ...
    Field.SetField(width, height, R.drawable.image);
    ...

    return true;
}
```

Field.java

```
public class Field extends xxx{

private final Context mActivityContext;

public Field(Context activityContext)
{
    mActivityContext = activityContext;
}

public boolean SetField(int width, int height, int fn)
{
    ImageView mImage = (ImageView) ((Activity) mActivityContext).findViewById(fn);
...
}
```

but it doesn't work!

mImage contains null image...

I can't find how can image contain outside of the activity.

Can you help me about how to implement drawing an ImageView outside of the activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming mField is a member variable,

```
public class ImageRenderer implements Renderer {
Field mField = null;
```

use that in `InitializeObject`. Your `Context` is null because it wasn't set when you called it statically.

```
private boolean InitializeObject(int width, int height)
{
...
mField.SetField(width, height, R.drawable.image);
...

return true;
}
```

After you have set

```
 mField = new Field(mActivityContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this  (emptyimage is the image i have in my drawable)

```
mImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.emptyimage);
```